# Certificate chain is incomplete issue

Tags: ssl, nginx, encryption, https, ssl-certificate

Here are the *crt* and *ca-bundle* file from Comodo's email:

> Attached to this email you should find a .zip file containing:
>
> Your PositiveSSL Wildcard Certificate - STAR_domain_com.crt Your
>   Apache "bundle" file - STAR_domain_com.ca-bundle

How can I install this properly with NGINX?

The way I did it is through this:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name *.domain.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_domain_com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/STAR_domain_com.key;

  ssl_session_timeout 5m;
  ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Then I checked both crt and key file's modolus and it is the same (just to be sure).

But after checking with ssllabs.com I get this issue:

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete

What could be wrong in my configuration?

Comment: You need to concatenate your certificate file with the bundle file to create a new file. Point [`ssl_certificate`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) to this new file that contains all of the certificates.

Comment: @RichardSmith isn't the `*.ca-bundle` is already concatenated?

Comment: It contains multiple certificates making up the CA chain. Nginx just needs it to begin with your certificate. These are text files, so you can easily inspect them.

Comment: @RichardSmith okay so I did `$ cat STAR_domain_com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt  COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.
crt > ssl-bundle.crt` still SSLchecker is not accepting my website as secure, the browser Chrome / Firefox has the green lock on though

Comment: This really belongs on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=Certificate+chain+is+incomplete). The `.crt` file should contain your cert and all intermediate certs leading up to but not including the root CA cert. Test the chain with `openssl s_client -servername domain.com -connect domain.com:443`